# Default slot or named slot not working on "router-view" in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Passing a header component as a named slot into `router-view`. But `router-view` not exactly displaying it. Normally this was work in **vue 2**. But it's not with **vue 3**. Is the way doing it changed or is it impossible to do it now?

**header component**

```html
<template>
  <header id="g-header">
    <figure>
      <img id="logo"
           src="@/assets/images/logo.jpg"
           alt="The beautiful MDN logo.">
    </figure>
    <nav id="g-nav" class="flex justify-space-between">
      <a v-for="(link, idx) in links" :key="idx"
         class="flex justify-center align-center capitalize"
         :href="link.val">{{ link.text }}</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>
```

**router-view component**

```html
<template>
  <div id="moduleA" class="modules">
    <router-view class="moduleA-children">
      <template #header>
        <app-header></app-header>
      </template>
    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

**children view component**

```html
<template>
  <div id="step1">
    <slot name="header"></slot>
    <div class="row">the named slot OR default slot not showing</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or do I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue Router 4, `<router-view>` exposes the component to render as a [`v-slot` prop, named `Component`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view-s-v-slot), which would be used with the built-in `<component>` tag. You could pass any slots to the component within that `<component>` tag:

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <component :is="Component">
    <template #header>
      <app-header></app-header>
    </template>
  </component>
</router-view>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-slots-to-router-view-children-in-vue-router-4-i6t2q?file=/src/App.vue:48-268)